# 2004 Honda Civic ex rpm spike and lose acceleration.

Tags: honda, transmission, civic, rpm

I have a 2004 Honda Civic. Sometimes when pushing on the gas at a slow pace around town the rpm jump up and it's difficult to accelerate. Once doing 60 it doesn't appear to do it. Does the transmission need flushed? I have an automatic transmission with 187,677 miles.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This symptom suggests a slipping clutch in the transmission. To rule out other problems make sure the fluid is full and no leaks are present. The fluid should be red not brown.  Changing the fluid, even if it is of poor quality, is unlikely to change the felt clutch slip symptom. In almost all cases like this the transmission will need substantial repairs.